# React Native Version Mismatch Error - Expo

Tags: react-native, expo

Getting the following message when I init a project and then launch the Xcode emulator:

```
"React Native version mismatch.

Javascript version: 0.59.10
Native version: 0.61.4-undefined

..."
```

My package.json:

```
{
    "name": "tinder-react-native",
    "description": "Tinder React Native clone",
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "author": "Steven Persia",
    "licence": "MIT",
    "homepage": "https://github.com/stevenpersia/tinder-react-native",
    "private": true,
    "scripts": {
        "lint": "eslint ./components ./containers --fix",
        "start": "node node_modules/react-native/local-cli/cli.js start",
        "test": "jest"
    },
    "dependencies": {
        "expo": "^37.0.8",
        "react": "16.6.3",
        "react-native": "^0.59.10",
        "react-native-card-stack-swiper": "^1.1.0",
        "react-native-gesture-handler": "^1.0.12",
        "react-navigation": "^3.0.9"
    },
    "devDependencies": {
        "babel-jest": "^24.8.0",
        "eslint": "^6.6.0",
        "eslint-config-standard": "^14.1.0",
        "eslint-plugin-import": "^2.18.2",
        "eslint-plugin-node": "^10.0.0",
        "eslint-plugin-promise": "^4.2.1",
        "eslint-plugin-react": "^7.16.0",
        "eslint-plugin-react-native": "^3.8.1",
        "eslint-plugin-standard": "^4.0.1",
        "jest": "^24.8.0",
        "metro-react-native-babel-preset": "0.51.1",
        "react-test-renderer": "16.6.3"
    },
    "jest": {
        "preset": "react-native",
        "transform": {
            "node_modules/react-native/.+\\.js$": "<rootDir>/node_modules/react-native/jest/preprocessor.js"
        }
    },
    "rnpm": {
        "assets": [
            "./assets/fonts/"
        ]
    }
}
```

My app.json (it didn't have a sdkVersion):

```
{
  "name": "tinderReact",
}
```

Does anyone know what is going on here and can help me? This is realllllllly frustrating.
Some information: I don't have watchman installed. I don't know what to do since there was no sdkVersion in app.json to begin with.

Comment: How did you create the project? Did you use `react-native-cli`, or `expo-cli`?

Comment: Did you ever solved this problem?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure why last answer is voted -1. But I have faced this issue and this is real reason in case of Android Build:

If android build you get this issue, Add below lines in your app/build.gradle file:

```
implementation ('com.facebook.react:react-native:0.66.2(same as your package.json react-native version)'){
        version {
            strictly '0.66.2'
        }
    }  // From node_modules
```

Answer (score -1):

```
I was also struggling with this. 

Somebody has added this https://bintray.com/weimob/maven/react-native/0.55.3 and it will break all React Native Android builds that specify jcenter() in project's repositories.

To avoid this issue, you should force React Native version in android/app/build.gradle file like this compile ("com.facebook.react:react-native:0.52.0") { force = true }. Change 0.52.0 to version you're using.
```

https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/19259#issuecomment-389064401

I found this one google and I think this might be help with you.

Regards